# Позиционирование несколько картинок как фон, чтобы не разъезжались

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, sass, scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать на фоне три картинки(коробочки), чтобы они стояли вместе и уменьшались от масштабирования браузера. Делал через абсолют, лефт, топ и размер картинок прописывал в rem и процентах. Они просто разъезжаются. Перепробовал всё, бился не один час. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется проще в Фотошопе отредачить уже готовый вариант с картинками(да костыль но хоть что то).
А вообще такие вещи только через absolute и процентами указывать top left right bottom и с помощью медиа - запросов корректировать поведение при адаптиве